# Allocating new memory in a variable inside a while loop

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, queue, artificial-intelligence

I have a `Town` class which represents the nodes in my graph like this:

```
class Town
{
public:
    Town();
public:
    Town* _parent;

    int _name;
    int _row;
    int _column;
    State _state;

    vector<Town*> _neighbors;
};
```

I have a `Map` class which contains a 2D vector of Towns and pretty much makes my random graph.

```
class Map
{
public:
    Map(const int elements, const int size, const int seed);
public: 
    vector <vector<Town> > _map;
    vector <Town*> _towns;
    vector <vector<int> > _adjacency;
    vector <vector<double> > _mDistance;
    vector <Line> _edges;

    const int _elements;
    const int _size;

    Town* _start;
    Town* _exit;
};
```

Then my AI class receives a `Map` object and solves it depending on the algorithm, right now I am implementing Astar.

```
class AI
{
private:
    struct TownWithCost
    {
        Town town;
        double cost;
    };

    struct OrderByTotalCost
    {
        bool operator()(TownWithCost lfs, TownWithCost rhs)
        {
            return lfs.cost > rhs.cost;
        }
    };
public:
    AI(Map map);
private:
    bool AStar(Town* town);

    double GetTotalCost(Town town);

public:
    bool _success;
private:
    Map _map;
};
```

Here is my Astar implementation:

```
bool AI::AStar(Town* town)
{
    AI::OrderByTotalCost comparator;
    vector<TownWithCost> priorityQueue;

    TownWithCost currentTown = { *town, 0 };
    Town temp = currentTown.town;

    priorityQueue.push_back(currentTown);

    SetEnvironment(temp, State::visited);

    while (!priorityQueue.empty())
    {
        currentTown = priorityQueue.front();
        Town temp = currentTown.town;

        priorityQueue.erase(priorityQueue.begin());

        SetEnvironment(temp, State::visited);
        PrintEnvironment();

        if (temp._name == _map._exit->_name)
        {
            return true;
        }

        vector <Town*> neighbors = town->_neighbors;

        for each (Town* neighbor in neighbors)
        {
            Town tempNeighbor = *neighbor;

            if (tempNeighbor._state == State::town)
            {
                tempNeighbor._parent = &temp;
                TownWithCost neighborWithCost = { tempNeighbor, GetTotalCost(tempNeighbor) };

                priorityQueue.push_back(neighborWithCost);
            }
        }
        make_heap(priorityQueue.begin(), priorityQueue.end(), comparator);
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can probably notice I don't have yet implemented looking inside the `priorityQueue` to see if I already have a `Town` in there and compare the costs to see which one I want to keep but I plan on implementing that after I solve my current problem.

What my problem is, is that I do not want to have pointers inside the `priorityQueue`. I am trying to make temp variables which will copy a Town and it's cost from a certain path.

Let's say I start from Town `9`.

`9` has neighbors `0`, `7`, `8`, `3` specifically the `priorityQueue` at the first loop looks like this:

[image: Parent 9]

Then I get `3` as my currentTown and I am checking it's neighbors.

The moment I reach the line `Town temp = currentTown.town;` for the second time the parents of each element in the `priorityQueue` are being set to `3`. Now I understand why this is happening, what I don't understand is how to prevent this.

[image: Parent changed to 3]

What I basically need is `priorityQueue` to store the same Towns (not same memory addresses) with different parents and different costs (I have already taken care of the separate cost with the struct `TownWithCost`). So all in all make copies each time.

For example I can get from `9` to `0` directly with total cost 81 but I can also get to `0` through `3` (`9 -> 3 -> 0`) with total cost 50. I want to be able to differentiate these two.

How do I differentiate between them in my `priorityQueue` and how do I avoid resetting the parents or in other words how do I allocate another part of memory to the `Town temp` each time the loop runs so I can have different temps each time?

If you have another way (as newbie friendly as possible) of doing this then feel free to say it.

Comment: Why are you using a vector of pointers? Why not just a vector of objects?

Comment: @caps do you mean the `priorityQueue`? Because I have that as a vector of `TownWithCost` which uses `Town` and `int`. Unless you are talking about the `Town* _parent` variable. I don't know any other way to lead me from a town back to the Town which it came from without pointers.

Comment: I mean this member of Map: `vector <Town*> _towns;`

Comment: I did that because each vector element pointed to a `_map[][]` Town element. But don't worry about that, that vector is not being used by Astar at all.

Comment: It did that is why I'm asking it again. The specific thing I am asking is *how to allocate new memory in a variable inside a while loop* or *how else can I achieve the priority queue for Astar*

Comment: @SilliconTouch Allocating memory for a variable using `new` inside a while loop doesn't make a difference as to it's working in any other place. I suppose the logic of your overall memory management has some flaws! (Please @<address> me in comments)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry I forgot the @. But if it can't be done that way (even with a copy constructor) how else would it be possible to implement the queue of a simple A-star such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing by value instances of `Map` and this class doesn't have a copy constructor or assignment operator. When this class is shallow copied (ala memcpy) `vector` instances will cause a crash when they are destroyed (multiple times).

Try working with pointers or references. Will also work faster.

Comment: if you mean doing everything by pointers in Astar it was the first thing I did and it threw the error `invalid heap` because `GetTotalCost()` was changing the cost inside each element of the heap, that is why I tried copying everything which I did not succeed in.

Comment: No problem. performance is kept for last. But you need to write copy constructors and assignment operators.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a vector of index pointing to an array or vector of the towns. No need for pointers. But personally, I'd prefer to use std:shared_ptr instead.

Comment: I thought of instead storing `Town` in `TownWithCost` I could store a vector of indexes every time which would be pretty much the path every time but I am trying to maybe find a more elegant way of achieving my goal. But if I can't do this with just having copies then in the end I might try the vector way again. Also I have heard a lot of people talking about `std::shared_ptr` but I personally have no experience with it since I'm new to C++ (and programming in general) that is why I did not use it.